# Building 32-Bit on a 64-Bit system

Tags: 64bit, cross-compilation, 32bit, configure

I'm trying to build the PHP memcache extension (v2.2.6) for i386 (32bit) on my x86_64 Ubuntu 11.04.

`./configure` uses config.guess by default (which outputs `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` on my system) but I want to override that.

How would I have to proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need two things to cross-compile: a compiler that can generate code for the target architecture, and the static libraries (`*.a`) for the target architecture. Install at least the [`libc6-dev-i386`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6-dev-i386)   [image: Install libc6-dev-i386] packages, and possibly other [`lib32.*-dev` packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=natty&searchon=names&keywords=lib32). The `libc6-dev-i386` also pulls in the components of gcc needed for cross-compilation in the [`gcc-multilib` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-multilib)   [image: Install gcc-multilib]. Then tell gcc to compile for i386 by passing it the `-m32` flag through the `CFLAGS` variable.

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386 lib32ncurses5-dev … # whatever 32-bit libraries you need
export CFLAGS='-m32'
./configure …
```

If you don't find all the libraries you need, it'll probably be easier to install a 32-bit Ubuntu in a [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot). Ubuntu ships [dchroot](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=dchroot)   [image: Install dchroot] from the [Debian buildd project](https://web.archive.org/web/20170314073938/https://alioth.debian.org/projects/buildd-tools/), which makes running a chrooted system easy. Use [debootstrap](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=debootstrap)   [image: Install debootstrap] to perform the installation. There's a reasonable-looking [dchroot tutorial on the Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=24575).

Comment: Hi,There was some issue in this images used in this answer!! Could you change it.

Comment: @saravanakumar Done. If you see links to http://bit.ly/software-small please update them to http://hostmar.co/software-small , unfortunately the old URL no longer works. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/548/how-to-post-links-that-integrate-with-the-software-center